# ssh-add make the Jenkins pipline job to fail

Tags: docker, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, ssh-keys

Jenkins (2.162), updated modules. I need to to add private github dependencies for cargo build. So, I need store SSH key into Jenkins container before `cargo build`.

I did:

```
stage('Build') {
    steps{
        script {
            dir('api'){
                withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'GitKeyText', variable: 'ID_RSA')]) {
                    sh '''
                        set +x
                        eval `ssh-agent -s`
                        mkdir ~/.ssh
                        echo ${ID_RSA} >~/.ssh/id_rsa
                        chmod go-r ~/.ssh/id_rsa
                        ssh-add
                        cargo build
                    '''
                }
            }
            input message: "wait"
        }
    }
}
```

All looks good and this sequence of command work well manually inside the docker container. But, Jenkins job had been failing at `ssh-add` without any error messages. Just `ERROR: script returned exit code 1` at the end of the Jenkins console log.

add01:
I added echo comment to the code, and changed `set +x` to `set -x`

no output from `ssh-add` (console output)

```
.....
+ echo before ssh-add
before ssh-add
+ ssh-add
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
Post stage
.....
```

Comment: `set +x` is part of *why* you don't have any logging. If you did have `set -x` tracing enabled, you (and thus we) would at least know which specific step was returning a nonzero status.

Comment: That said, having a whole bunch of potentially-concurrent jobs all overwriting the same `~/.ssh/id_rsa` file is a Really Bad Idea. Why not use a different file per job? You can, and should, pass `ssh-add` a specific filename for the key to add.

Comment: Also, `mkdir ~/.ssh` is going to fail when the file already exists. Use the `-p` argument to suppress that, as in `mkdir -p ~/.ssh` (but again, don't use `~/.ssh` at all, as discussed above).

Comment: Sorry for unclear description. "Jenkins container" - i mean build inside container. So each time it is new independent files.

Comment: `set +/- x` don't add any new information. `ssh-add` has no output.

Comment: What that tells us, which wasn't shown before, is that `ssh-add` actually runs -- which is to say, no prior step returned a nonzero exit status and caused early termination. So there genuinely is new information provided.

Comment: That said, your log doesn't make any sense -- maybe you deleted the `+ cargo build` line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [Jenkins SSH Agent Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+Agent+Plugin).
All work as intended.

```
script {
    dir('contract_api'){
        sshagent(['GitSSHcred']) {
            sh 'cargo build'
        }
    }
}
```